# Linearity of filtering system on concatenated signals

Tags: matlab, filter, signal-processing

I have a signal s[n] and a bandpass filter that filters out very low and very high frequency components of the signal. I want to store the signal into an Matlab array and put it through the filter.

However, I cannot store s[n] in Matlab because the allocated memory is not sufficient to contain such long signal. I decided to split the signal into N segments, and put each segment through that bandpass filter, and lastly assemble them after filtering.

I am wondering if there is any linearity issue with this approach. If this is not valid, then is there any other method that can achieve what I want? Thanks.

Comment: What would the length involved typically be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using an FIR filter you can using [convolution](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/conv.html):

```
x = rand(1000,1)
b = fir1(100, 0.5)
y1 = zeros(1100, 1)
% compute the response using the first 400 points of x
y1(1:500) = conv(x(1:400),b)
% compute the response using the last 600 points of x
y1(401:1100) = y1(401:1100) + conv(x(401:1000),b)
% compute the whole response just to compare
y2 = conv(x,b)
```

Note that the length of conv(a,b) is length(a) + lenght(b) - 1

But the total response will have the same length of your approach, you are probably going to have the same memory problem.

Answer (score 0):

Overlap-add and overlap-save are methods to deal with segmented windows of data when doing FFT fast convolution, but should work with segmented direct linear convolution with (finite) FIR filter kernels as well.

When doing IIR filtering, you need to save and restore the internal filter state across segment boundaries.

If you don't do the above, then you will usually end up with transient clicks at the block boundaries.